# What's the url being produced here

Tags: php, url, zend-framework, zend-route, zend-view

I'm getting a Route error from this line. Can someone tell me what's the final form of the url being built here:

```
$this->url(array('locate'=>'rom'), 'locate', true);
```

Comment: What is the route error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody can tell you the URL as you have not provided enough details such as the route definition.

What I can tell you is that the call to the URL helper is passing the following:

- Set the `locate` parameter to "rom"
- Use the `locate` route
- Reset all parameters to their defaults.

Regarding the last point; the defaults will be set in the route definition. If they are not defined there, they will fall back to the framework defaults of...

- `controller` = "index"
- `action` = "index"
- `module` = "default"